# jQuery check value in option list and textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check if the option in a form is 'Yes' and text is empty if correct error.

My code is

```
if($('#option').val() == 'Yes'){
   if ( $('#text').val() =='') 
       $('#contact_noyes').css('border','1px solid red');

   error = true;
}
```

The error puts a red border round the text box. Which works ok.

Comment: And what is your problem then?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to see if your select element is currently on the Yes option correct? If so, you will need to change your code so it checks the value of the select element, NOT the option within the select.

So it'll probably look like this instead:

```
if($('#select').val() == 'Yes'){
   if ( $('#text').val() =='') 
       $('#contact_noyes').css('border','1px solid red');

   error = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to check the `option` value selected on a `select` tag you have to check the `select` element, not the `option` one.

So instead of this:

```
if($('#option').val() == 'Yes'){
```

You have to write this:

```
if($('#select').val() == 'Yes'){
```

This will return the value of the selected `option` in your `select` tag

Make sure you check value on `select` tag, not `option` one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your issue is exactly but I think it may have something to dow with your opening and closing brackets you're omitting them for the second `if`. Do you only want `error` to be true if both of those conditions are true or just the `$('#select')`.

So, your code with proper brackets is:

```
if ($('#select').val() == 'Yes') {
  if ($('#text').val() =='') {
    $('#contact_noyes').css('border','1px solid red');
    error = true;
  }
}
```

You can join the `if`s and do:

```
if ($('#select').val() == 'Yes' && $('#text').val() =='') {
  $('#contact_noyes').css('border','1px solid red');
  error = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ur code works pretty fine. U can use the `change event`.
Check this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/zL2yrw2h/) for a working example.

Hope it useful!